# Change from F2 to F1 status? Visa stamp already there

Tags: visas, usa

I am in the US on an F2 status. When I went to my home country a few months ago, I had the F1 visa stamped on my passport. I didn't enter the US as F1 because the earliest admission date had not arrived. I used my older F2 visa to enter the US.

Now, to change my status, I have the option of flying back to my country, or another country that I am allowed to enter, and coming back. That will be expensive. Can I go through US immigration without actually boarding a plane flying outside?

Comment: Are you near a land border? You can walk up to a land border crossing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply for a [change in immigration status](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/change-my-nonimmigrant-status-category/change-my-nonimmigrant-status).

In your particular case, as you are a dependent of an F-1 visa holder, you can attend elementary, middle, or high school without needing to change your status. However, to attend a post-secondary institution, you must change your status.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks to me like this is the process to follow if I didn't have the F1 visa stamped on my passport already. But I do. Are you sure I have to go through all this to avoid flying to Canada, for example?

Comment: @WaqarAqeel Since you entered the U.S. using your F-2 visa, you're in the U.S. on that status. You will need to change your status to avoid violating your status. See the linked page for more info.

Comment: @WaqarAqeel A change in status costs hundreds of dollars and can take quite a long time to process, so leaving the country somewhere and re-entering is often more practical, even though it's inconvenient. You should contact the international students office at your school, as this is doubtless something they've assisted with before too.

Comment: @ZachLipton You should post a separate answer with that.

Comment: @WaqarAqeel: US visas are only for entry. The fact that you have an F-1 visa is irrelevant unless you leave the US and use it to enter. When in the US, visas do not matter; the only thing that matters is the status you were admitted on on your I-94. You need to apply for Change of Status if you want to change to a different nonimmigrant status without leaving the US.

Comment: @WaqarAqeel to add to user102008's comment, the change of status application is the only way to change your status without leaving the US. It does not matter whether you have an F-1 visa or not. (And, if someone who doesn't have an F-1 visa makes a successful change-of-status application, they do not *get* an F-1 visa; they just get to remain in the US in F-1 status.) Since you do have the visa, you have the additional option of leaving and reentering the US instead of changing status. You can go to Canada or Mexico if you don't want to fly.